Kubuntu takes around 1+ minute to startup
I'm wondering why my startup takes too long. I don't know if this is normal in Kubuntu, I'm coming from Windows where it just takes me around 10-20 seconds to bootup to login screen. But now it takes around a minute and a half to bootup to login.
I have a video link that shows how long it takes to load up; I couldn't record the first 10 seconds but it shows the same thing throughout the whole first half of the video. Here's the link to the video: https://streamable.com/kc5cah.
I tried disabling parameter in GRUB here's the result:
loid-b@loid-b:~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=cfd64b2b-38f2-4412-a305-ad2df6cd31b0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 libata.force=2.00:disable

loid-b@loid-b:~$ sudo dmesg | grep libata.force
[sudo] password for loid-b: 
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=cfd64b2b-38f2-4412-a305-ad2df6cd31b0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 libata.force=2.00:disable
[    0.036289] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-26-generic root=UUID=cfd64b2b-38f2-4412-a305-ad2df6cd31b0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 libata.force=2.00:disable
loid-b@loid-b:~$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 'SATA'
06:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 61)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1043:18f1]
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

I also took pictures:







I also ran these commands below which shows the output:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-path & lsblk -o VENDOR,MODEL,NAME
loid-b@loid-b:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-path
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr  8 18:23 pci-0000:03:00.0-nvme-1 -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr  8 18:23 pci-0000:03:00.0-nvme-1-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr  8 18:23 pci-0000:03:00.0-nvme-1-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
loid-b@loid-b:~$ lsblk -o VENDOR,MODEL,NAME
VENDOR MODEL               NAME
                           loop0
                           loop1
                           loop2
                           loop3
                           loop4
                           loop5
                           loop6
                           loop7
                           loop8
                           loop9
                           loop10
       INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8 nvme0n1
                           ├─nvme0n1p1
                           └─nvme0n1p2

I tried to check in BIOS and see if I could do something with the SATA but I don't see any option to disable it pics below:



I did some of these things to check my system:
loid-b@loid-b:~$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 6.241s (firmware) + 3.607s (loader) + 1min 5.863s (kernel) + 9.020s (userspace) = 1min 24.732s 
graphical.target reached after 8.994s in userspace.

And when I systemd-analyze blame this showed up:
loid-b@loid-b:~$ systemd-analyze blame
9min 44.584s dev-loop2.device
9min 44.581s dev-loop6.device
9min 44.580s dev-loop5.device
9min 44.569s dev-loop1.device
9min 44.567s dev-loop0.device
9min 44.565s dev-loop7.device
9min 44.563s dev-loop4.device
9min 44.560s dev-loop3.device
      5.042s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.336s plymouth-quit.service
      1.997s NetworkManager.service
      1.581s dev-loop9.device
       830ms gpu-manager.service
       678ms snapd.service
       545ms udisks2.service
       426ms upower.service
       417ms accounts-daemon.service
       411ms apport.service
       369ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
       290ms ModemManager.service
       290ms systemd-logind.service
       284ms power-profiles-daemon.service
       266ms polkit.service
       225ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       199ms switcheroo-control.service
       195ms e2scrub_reap.service
       184ms snapd.seeded.service
       181ms blueman-mechanism.service
       151ms user@1000.service
       133ms bluetooth.service
       130ms systemd-resolved.service
       118ms update-notifier-download.service
       118ms rsyslog.service
       111ms systemd-journald.service
       106ms secureboot-db.service
        89ms avahi-daemon.service
        86ms smartmontools.service
        86ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        82ms apparmor.service
        76ms grub-common.service
        75ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        68ms keyboard-setup.service
        63ms dbus.service
        57ms wpa_supplicant.service
        56ms systemd-udevd.service
        45ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        45ms snapd.apparmor.service
        39ms thermald.service
        38ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        38ms dev-hugepages.mount
        38ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
        37ms dev-mqueue.mount
        36ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        36ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
        34ms cups.service
        33ms systemd-modules-load.service
        32ms snapd.socket
        31ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        30ms modprobe@configfs.service
        30ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3ABD\x2d6C66.service
        30ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        29ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service
        28ms boot-efi.mount
        28ms modprobe@drm.service
        26ms snap-bare-5.mount
        26ms modprobe@fuse.service
        24ms snap-core20-2182.mount
        23ms alsa-restore.service
        22ms plymouth-start.service
        22ms snap-core22-864.mount
        21ms systemd-binfmt.service
        20ms snap-firefox-3216.mount
        19ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service
        19ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
        17ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-141.mount
        16ms kerneloops.service
        15ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
        15ms snap-discord-182.mount
        14ms snap-snapd-20092.mount
        13ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
        13ms plymouth-read-write.service
        13ms snap-spotify-75.mount
        12ms systemd-sysusers.service
        12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        11ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        11ms console-setup.service
        11ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
        10ms systemd-rfkill.service
         9ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         9ms systemd-sysctl.service
         8ms systemd-random-seed.service
         8ms sddm.service
         7ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
         5ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         5ms dev-loop8.device
         5ms nvidia-persistenced.service
         4ms ufw.service
         4ms rtkit-daemon.service
         4ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
         3ms swapfile.swap
         3ms modprobe@loop.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms setvtrgb.service

This is the critical chain of it:
loid-b@loid-b:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @8.994s
└─multi-user.target @8.994s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.977s +16ms
    └─network-online.target @8.953s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @3.909s +5.042s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.892s +1.997s
          └─dbus.service @1.821s +63ms
            └─basic.target @1.706s
              └─sockets.target @1.706s
                └─snapd.socket @1.673s +32ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.668s
                    └─systemd-resolved.service @1.536s +130ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.501s +30ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.493s
                          └─run-credentials-systemd\x2dresolved.service.mount @2.321s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @390ms
                              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @378ms +12ms
                                └─systemd-sysusers.service @364ms +12ms
                                  └─systemd-remount-fs.service @314ms +45ms
                                    └─systemd-journald.socket @280ms
                                      └─system.slice @235ms
                                        └─-.slice @235ms

Here are some info:
    Kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic
    arch: x86_64
    Desktop Environment & Version : KDE 5.27.8
    Distribution: Ubuntu 23.10
    Product: TUF Gaming FX505DD_FX505DD
    512GB PCIe® 3.0 NVMe™ M.2 SSD


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

After a looong debugging session, turns out the SATA controller on the motherboard is misbehaving, polling a device which isn't even connected to the bus, failing at it and holding back the whole startup process;
By adding the kernel parameter libata.force=2:rstonce (where 2 is the non-existing device as listed by dmesg) OP and I were able to shove off 1 minute off the previous 1 minute and 30 seconds boot time, ultimately dropping the total boot time to just about 30 seconds.
Specifically the rstonce flag will tell libata to send just a single reset command to the specified device, ultimately avoiding wasting time on a device when this isn't responding to reset commands (for any reason: in this case the controller was polling a non-existing device, but this will work also in case of a failing drive which is not responding to reset commands).
